# MySQL LEFT JOIN where joined table is null

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My current SQL is:

```
SELECT * FROM `node`
LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_area_of_study_category`
ON `field_data_field_area_of_study_category`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
WHERE `node`.`type` = 'area_of_study'
GROUP BY `node`.`nid`
```

For now, to make it work I run a `foreach` loop to `is_null()` on the column.

I'm trying to emulate the `is_null()` check within the SQL query.

Thanks for reading.

**EDIT**
This is the foreach loop that runs the `is_null()`. I think a better way to ask my question would be: **how do make the SQL return *only* rows from the node table where there is no matching field_data_field_area_of_study_category table?**

```
foreach($aos_nodes as $aos_node):
  if (is_null($aos_node->field_area_of_study_category_tid)):
    $menu_item_display[$aos_node->title] = array(
      'id' => $aos_node->nid,
      'type' => 'node',
      'children_markup' => '',
      'icon' => '',
      'name' => $aos_node->title,
      'href' => drupal_get_path_alias('node/'.$aos_node->nid),
    );
  endif;
endforeach;
```

Comment: More specifically to @SergeiTulentsev - What do you want to do if the joined value is null?

Comment: `WHERE field IS NULL`?  [`ISNULL(field)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_isnull)?  [`IFNULL(field, 0)`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)?

Comment: I think Rocket is onto exactly what I'm asking for. I've edited my question. I'm going to try Rocket's suggestions, and think of a better way to articulate my question. Thanks for reading so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To return the rows where there isn't a matching one:

```
SELECT * FROM `node`
LEFT JOIN `field_data_field_area_of_study_category`
ON `field_data_field_area_of_study_category`.`entity_id` = `node`.`nid`
WHERE `node`.`type` = 'area_of_study' 
    and `field_data_field_area_of_study_category`.`entity_id` is null
GROUP BY `node`.`nid`
```

Additionally, you can use `not exists`:

```
select
    *
from
    node n
where
    n.type = 'area_of_study'
    and not exists (
        select 
            1 
        from 
            field_data_field_area_of_study_category f 
        where 
            f.entity_id = n.nid
    )
```

Comment: Added an answer w/ Community Wiki to forego rep points but at least get the answer there that you'll need.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. I was struggling trying to look up ways to use the ON syntax to filter results while LEFT JOINing, but this is 110% what I was looking for. Thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes, that mistake. For what it's worth, `ON` never filters out rows, it only specifies which rows from one table belong to rows for another table. The join type and the where clause are the two things that filter rows. It's a subtle difference (especially with inner joins), but a very important one as you write more and more complex SQL.

Comment: I really appreciate the elaboration.